# SQL SELECT statement with complicated 'if/else' requirement

Tags: mysql, sql, lookup-tables

I am using a MySQL database, here's my situation:

I need a select query to be able to get a list of projects that can be completed using N supplies, where N is an array of supplies.  This list of projects must include all projects that can be completed using any or all of N supplies, but can not include any projects that require supplies not listed in N. *(e.g. in the make sketch project from the tables below paper has no substitute; however, pencil can be substituted by pen. If the query searches for projects that can be completed using pencil, pen, and pencil sharpener then 'make sketch' should not return as a project that can be completed, even though it uses some of the supplies listed)*

Additionally, some of the supplies required by certain projects can be substituted by other supplies; however, just because one project can use a substitute supply item does not mean that another project would work with that same substitute. *(e.g. in the sharpen pencil project below pen cannot be a substitute for pencil, however, for make drawing it can)*

These are my tables:

```
Projects
+----+---------------------+
| id |        name         |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | make sketch         |
|  2 | sharpen pencil      |
|  3 | make paper airplane |
+----+---------------------+

Supplies
+----+------------------+
| id |       name       |
+----+------------------+
|  1 | paper            |
|  2 | pencil           |
|  3 | pen              |
|  4 | pencil sharpener |
+----+------------------+

ProjectSupplies
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | projectid |  supplyid  |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  1 |         1 |          1 |
|  2 |         1 |          2 |
|  3 |         2 |          2 |
|  4 |         2 |          4 |
|  5 |         3 |          1 |
+----+-----------+------------+

SubstituteSupplies
+-------------------+------------+
| projectsuppliesid |  supplyid  |
+-------------------+------------+
|                 2 |          3 |
+-------------------+------------+
```

The data isn't exhaustive by any means but you should get the point.

This is the query I came up with *previous to updating the database*(see update below), however, it breaks the rules because the query result includes projects that require paper simply because it `COUNT`'s both the supplyid and the substitute as two separate requirements rather than as simply fulfilling the same supply requirement.

```
SELECT projects.name FROM supplies
INNER JOIN projectsupplies ON supplyid = supplies.id OR substitute = supplies.id
INNER JOIN projects ON projects.id = projectid
WHERE supplies.id IN (2,3,4)
GROUP BY projects.name
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3
ORDER BY projects.id
```

**Is there a way to turn this:**

```
INNER JOIN projectsupplies ON supplyid = supplies.id OR substitute = supplies.id
```

**into essentially this:**

```
INNER JOIN projectsupplies ON (supplies.id = supplyid) ? (supplies.id = supplyid) : (supplies.id = substitute)
```

**or something similar to that using an if statement or whatever in order to make the query result correct?**

**One problem that I had been experiencing is that the above query will return 'make sketch' as a valid project even though, as specified in the query, there is no paper.**

The end goal is to be able to accomplish this on a large scale with many projects and many supplies.

**UPDATE:** I found an issue in the design of my database that made it impossible to allow a supply to have more than one substitute. I corrected the problem to allow for many substitutes, and updated the tables above as necessary, so now the `SELECT` query above is no longer applicable.  I still, however, need to accomplish the same goal that is mentioned at the top of this post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'OR' at the query level tends to be translated into UNION.

---

#### After the schema changed significantly

```
(SELECT projectid, supplyid FROM ProjectSupplies
 UNION
 SELECT ps.Projectid, ss.supplyid
   FROM SubstituteSupplies AS ss
   JOIN ProjectSupplies    AS ps
     ON ss.ProjectSuppliesID = ps.ID
)
```

And plugging that into the bigger query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name
  FROM supplies AS s
  JOIN (SELECT projectid, supplyid FROM ProjectSupplies
        UNION
        SELECT ps.Projectid, ss.supplyid
          FROM SubstituteSupplies AS ss
          JOIN ProjectSupplies    AS ps
            ON ss.ProjectSuppliesID = ps.ID
       )        AS ps ON s.id = ps.supplyid
  JOIN projects AS p  ON p.id = ps.projectid
 WHERE s.id IN (2,3,4)
 GROUP BY p.id, p.name
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3
 ORDER BY p.id;
```

(Note that at this stage, I've not verified whether the rest of the query is sound; I've only addressed how to get both supplies and substitute supplies into the joining operations.)

When run against IBM Informix Dynamic Server 11.70.FC2 on Mac OS X 10.7.5, the output from the sample data and the query above is:

```
1   make sketch
2   sharpen pencil
```

Clearly, this is not correct; project 1 needs paper to be completed, but that is not one of the supplies available and there isn't a substitute that's available.  So, the outer query is also not valid.

---

#### Fixing the main query

The projects that can be completed with a given supply list (here supplies 2, 3, 4) are those projects for which every necessary supply or substitute supply is in the list of supplies available.  One gotcha is to ensure that if there is a substitute supply available but one non-substitutable supply is missing, the project is not completable.

So, for instance, Project 1 requires a supply of SupplyID 1 and either SupplyID 2 or in the alternative SupplyID 3; the fact that both 2 and 3 are available is not sufficient.  In this example, there's only one substitute, but in general, there could be many SupplyIDs that are needed, and many of them could have substitutes.  So, considerable care is required.

#### Applying Test-Driven Query Design (TDQD)

When facing a complex query, I build it up step by step.  Having found that original main query misses the mark, I'm going to have to go about building it step by step, and the result is moderately complex, but comprehensible because the steps are explained.  There's also a key design step — the clever bit of the algorithm — to come up with, but that comes with experience.

One criterion is that each project needs to have all the supplies it uses available.  So, we need to know for each project how many different supplies it needs.  This is easy:

```
SELECT ProjectID, COUNT(*) AS ItemCount
  FROM ProjectSupplies
 GROUP BY ProjectID;
```

Result

```
1   2
2   2
3   1
```

Now comes the magic ingredient: the 'SupplyGroup'.  The UNION query generated previously needs to be extended to include a SupplyGroup.  The SupplyGroup corresponds to the 'desired' SupplyID in the ProjectSupplies table; the SupplyID is a SupplyID that will meet the project's criterion for equivalence, and is either the same SupplyID from ProjectSupplies or is the SupplyID from SubstituteSupplies:

```
SELECT ps.ProjectID, ps.SupplyID AS SupplyGroup, ps.SupplyID AS SupplyID
  FROM ProjectSupplies AS ps
UNION
SELECT ps.ProjectID, ps.SupplyID AS SupplyGroup, ss.SupplyID AS SupplyID
  FROM SubstituteSupplies AS ss
  JOIN ProjectSupplies    AS ps
    ON ss.ProjectSuppliesID = ps.ID;
```

Result

```
1   1   1
1   2   2
1   2   3
2   2   2
2   4   4
3   1   1
```

Now we need to generate a list of the ProjectIDs and the SupplyGroups that can be satisfied from the list `(2, 3, 4)` of available SupplyIDs:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProjectID, SupplyGroup
  FROM (SELECT ps.ProjectID, ps.SupplyID AS SupplyGroup, ps.SupplyID AS SupplyID
          FROM ProjectSupplies AS ps
        UNION
        SELECT ps.ProjectID, ps.SupplyID AS SupplyGroup, ss.SupplyID AS SupplyID
          FROM SubstituteSupplies AS ss
          JOIN ProjectSupplies    AS ps
            ON ss.ProjectSuppliesID = ps.ID
       ) AS i
 WHERE i.SupplyID IN (2, 3, 4);
```

Result

```
1   2
2   2
2   4
```

And, in fact, we need to count the number of distinct supply groups that are available for each project from that list:

```
SELECT ProjectID, COUNT(DISTINCT SupplyGroup) AS ItemCount
  FROM (SELECT ps.ProjectID, ps.SupplyID AS SupplyGroup, ps.SupplyID AS SupplyID
          FROM ProjectSupplies AS ps
        UNION
        SELECT ps.ProjectID, ps.SupplyID AS SupplyGroup, ss.SupplyID AS SupplyID
          FROM SubstituteSupplies AS ss
          JOIN ProjectSupplies    AS ps
            ON ss.ProjectSuppliesID = ps.ID
       ) AS i
 WHERE i.SupplyID IN (2, 3, 4)
 GROUP BY ProjectID;
```

Result

```
2   2
1   1
```

Now we need to join the first query with the second on project ID and item count, and join that with the projects table to list the project name:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.Name
  FROM (SELECT ProjectID, COUNT(DISTINCT SupplyGroup) AS ItemCount
          FROM (SELECT ps.ProjectID, ps.SupplyID AS SupplyGroup, ps.SupplyID AS SupplyID
                  FROM ProjectSupplies AS ps
                UNION
                SELECT ps.ProjectID, ps.SupplyID AS SupplyGroup, ss.SupplyID AS SupplyID
                  FROM SubstituteSupplies AS ss
                  JOIN ProjectSupplies    AS ps
                    ON ss.ProjectSuppliesID = ps.ID
               ) AS i
         WHERE i.SupplyID IN (2, 3, 4)
         GROUP BY ProjectID
       ) AS z
  JOIN (SELECT ProjectID, COUNT(*) AS ItemCount
          FROM ProjectSupplies
         GROUP BY ProjectID
       ) AS y
    ON z.ProjectID = y.ProjectID AND z.ItemCount = y.ItemCount
  JOIN Projects AS p ON p.ID = z.ProjectID
 ORDER BY p.ID, p.Name;
```

Result

```
2   sharpen pencil
```

And, given the data, I believe that is the correct result.

---

#### Before the schema changed significantly

The original version of the query was against a different table structure, where there was no SubstituteSupplies table and the ProjectSupplies table had an extra column `Substitute` that often contained a null but when it was not null, identified an alternative supply that would do.  The question also lists `(2,3,4,5)` in the IN list, and the aggregate was compared with 4, not 3.

You might well be able to do it with a UNION of two inner joins in a sub-select:

```
(SELECT projectid, supplyid FROM ProjectSupplies
 UNION
 SELECT projectid, substitute FROM ProjectSupplies WHERE substitute IS NOT NULL
)
```

That needs to be plugged into your main query:

```
SELECT p.name
  FROM supplies AS s
  JOIN (SELECT projectid, supplyid FROM ProjectSupplies
         UNION
        SELECT projectid, substitute AS supplyid
          FROM ProjectSupplies WHERE substitute IS NOT NULL
       )        AS ps ON s.id = ps.supplyid
  JOIN projects AS p  ON p.id = ps.projectid
 WHERE s.id IN (2,3,4,5)
 GROUP BY p.name
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 4
 ORDER BY p.id;
```

Comment: Received #1054 - Unknown column 'projects.name' in 'field list' (why?)

Comment: Because `projects.name` in the SELECT should be `p.name` because I used an alias `p` for `projects` (also `projects.id` in the ORDER BY too).  I'll fix.  (Note that I've not verified whether the rest of the query is sound; I've only addressed how to get both supplies and substitute supplies into the joining operations.)

Comment: I modified it and got it to work but it still counts both pen and pencil in the query and so `HAVING COUNT(*) <= 4` still returns make sketch as a result even though there is no paper, for some reason it doesn't recognize that there is no paper to be able to use for the first project.

Comment: I suspect the trouble is that you need the `COUNT(*)` to be equal to the number of supplies the project needs, which might be `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ProjectSupplies AS z WHERE z.ProjectID = p.ID)`, which is a correlated sub-query.

Comment: could you put it all together in your response for me to test out?

Comment: See the revision.  The effort involved in producing such answers is not commensurate with the reward one gets from SO for producing it.

Comment: Thank you so much for that great answer! I'll be honest, I don't think I fully understand everything in there right now, but I intend to study SQL more in depth and get to that point soon. Do you recommend any books in particular for learning advanced querying like this?  I'm sorry that you feel the reward was not worth it, but you have at least motivated me to 'hit the books' on SQL! One last question: Would you recommend a different approach rather than one long query like this (i.e. loading the information and using PHP or another server script to filter the data to fit the schema)?

Comment: The gripe about rewards is just a comment on the SQL tag; some questions are hard and take time to answer but not many people pay attention.  You've done what you can; I don't expect any more.  I'd suggest looking at Chris Date's "SQL and Relational Theory" book from O'Reilly, though I learned SQL long enough ago that I may be out of touch with how hard it is to learn.  It depends on the volume of data.  For small quantities, you can do all sorts of things; for large quantities, you want to avoid sending data over the network unnecessarily, so doing the SQL in the server is usually best.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
INNER JOIN projectsupplies ON supplies.id = IF(supplies.id = supplyid, supplyid, substitute)
```

Comment: I appreciate it but this doesn't work because supplyid will never be null, it will only be the case that sometimes there will be a substitute available

Comment: This gave me the same result.